# Something is downloading in background Linux

Tags: networking, download, linux-mint, streaming

My laptop boots normally to LinuxMint and immediately I like to open `gnome-system-monitor` but the shock is that something is downloading (the problem has been out 2 days ago) and nothing I run yet!

I did `iftop` in terminal but nothing strange, also I tried `nethogs` which showed nothing at all.

The more complicated when I reboot and same problem is there so I can't browse/surf Internet, no one connected to my network can browse any more it's absorbing the stream horribly!

After many reboots it will go to normal state(no background downloading). 
But really I can't figure out the problem going behind the scenes!

Any help would be appreciated... thanks.

[image: screenshot]

**Update**: I've just figured out the problem. I noticed that when a laptop running windows 7 connected to my network is downloading mine also downloading just like I am a node it goes through, and when it is off my laptop back to normal state! Can anyone think why such problem could happen?

Comment: Maybe check netstat, iirc the -b flag tells you what binary is doing the data transfer.

Comment: have you tried tcpdump ?I hope it might give you some clues.

Comment: FYI @wisdom you don't need to put "solved" in the title - just mark an accepted answer (as you've done) and the question is automatically marked as having been answered successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I know what the problem, it's just `ntop` process auto-started in startup and I tried to kill it so everything goes back OK, I read some about `ntop` as it monitors the network **USERS** usage ! 
sorry, I'm totally new to such network techniques but it's very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. `iftop` will show you what addresses your system is communicating with. The next time this starts happening, launch it to see where the data is going, and in another window, launch `netstat -tanp`. This will show you all active connections by IP address, and the `-p` flag will show what process on your system is responsible for the socket.

You can then correlate the two together and go from there.

Comment: I'll give it a try, actually I did try something similar by checking port from `iftop` then try this command `netstat -tpn | grep [prot]` but as I mentioned before nothing active while it's downloading which will drive me crazy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the snap package manager that was auto-updating. How I knew that. I installed `nethogs` using the command `sudo apt-get install nethogs`.
Then I get my machine network interface using the `ifconfig`, for me, it's a `wlan` interface, recently `wl`, since I'm using wifi. If you are using ethernet, then it will be `eth`, recently `en`.
Now I run the command `sudo nethogs interface`, where **interface** will be replaced with your net interface, for example `sudo nethogs wlp3s0`, hit enter and you will get all the programs that is using this network interface.